# Angular $rootScope.$broadcast not returning

Tags: angularjs, angular-kendo

I have AngularJS app with Angular Kendo as UI.
From one of the service I am sending broadcast to the controllers.

I am sending broadcast from service as below:

```
angular.module('MyAppModule')
.service('MyService', ['$rootScope',function($rootScope)
{    
    this.MESSAGE = "broadcast_msg";

    function sendBroadcast(message, data)
    {
        console.log("I get this log");

        $rootScope.$broadcast(message, data);

        console.log("I don't get this log");
    }

    function onSomeEvent(data)
    {
        sendBroadcast(MESSAGE, data)
    }

}]);
```

And in my controller:

```
angular.module('MyAppModule')
.controller('MyViewCtrl', ['$scope', 'MyService', function($scope, MyService)
{
    function init()
    {
        $scope.$on(MyService.MESSAGE, function(event, data) 
        {
            if( data.state == "some_state")
            {
                process()
            }
        });
    }

    function process()
    {
        // Destroy and remove current screen 
        $("#MyView").data("kendoMobileView").destroy(); // KendoMobileView is provide by Kendo 
        $("#MyView").remove(); // MyView - is that ID of kendo mobile view 
    }

}]);
```

If I comment `destroy` and `remove` calls then everything works fine.
But when I add then `$rootScope.$broadcats` does not return in the service.

I need to `remove` and `destroy` calls as to clear the screen and related states.

How to fix this issue?

**UPDATE**

I am deregistering broadcast listener as below from my controller.

```
// While registering listener   
var deregisterMessage = $scope.$on(MyService.MESSAGE, function(event, data) 
{
});

// At the time of removing screen 
if( deregisterMessage != null )
{
   deregisterMessage();
   deregisterMessage = null;
}
```

Comment: try tu using publish/subscribe

Comment: Do Angular by default supports it Or I need to use external/ third party library for pub/sub support?

Comment: when `init` get called? `$scope.$on(MyService.MESSAGE` not registered until `init` executes.

Comment: Init is getting called when view is loaded. And broadcast is sent after some time after view loads. But I have not given these details in sample code in the question to keep it simple.

Comment: you mean to say that, your broadcast is not working?

Comment: @Sravan: My broadcast works and also it reaches controller but problem is,  Code after broadcast call is not executing. that means $rootScope.$broadcast is not returning.

Comment: so, you are not gettting `data` from the broadcast. right?

Comment: Since you broadcasted using the rootscope, listen to it using the rootscope in the controller.
 `$rootScope.$on(MyService.MESSAGE, function(event, data)`

Comment: @Sravan: As I am getting broadcast I am also getting data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125991/discussion-between-sravan-and-a-user).

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `$rootScope.$on` from your controller, because even after your controller destroyed, event listener still exist and it cause memory leak.

it is better to create a service for each event you need to listen to or broadcast.

Comment: Not getting you exactly what you mean, I am calling `$scope.$on` in the controller. Also do I need to add `$scope.$on` in separate service and then register callback from my controller to get updates? can you provide example?